# How the Cosmos DB balances requests from different regions?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb

If I published my web application into azure with East US location but users are sending multiple requests from different regions (like West US, North Central US, South Central US) to my web application at that time, how does my web application balance those requests and how are users getting the data from requested location of Cosmos DB?

For example if the user sending request from West US location to my Web application located in East US at that time how user gets data from West US location of Cosmos DB?

Comment: Your users in West US are connecting to your web application in the East US. It is your application, not the users, that are then connecting to the db. You would need to have your application distributed into multiple regions so they can connect to the closest db instance.

Comment: Thanks Andres, for your valuable suggestion. it is possible only when ever I deployed my web application into multiple regions.

Comment: Correct. You would use Traffic Manager to route the users to the closest web application and then the application would connect to the closest db.